# UI didn't reflected the changes which fired from another thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have a WPF application, the UI part can simply understand as a `ListBox` which `ItemsSource` bind to a IList object, let's say the IList object instance is `classInstances`,  while each UI items in ListBox is just a checkbox which `IsChecked` property was **2 way bind** to each items in `classInstances`, more specific, the binding was on a Boolean property `AllowEntering`, then I can manipulate the  `AllowEntering` to control the UI, just as every WPF app would do.

Now say `classInstances` have 4 items in it, so should same have 4 checkbox in `ListBox`, all 4 checkbox are default in **un-checked** state, then I have a **ThreadPool thread** to timely scanning all the 'AllowEntering' properties, if they're false, then set it to true, as expecting, all 4 checkbox should get checked, the logic get much simplified:

```
// we have 4 instance in a IList, each instance 2 way bind to a checkbox, of course 
//implement INotifyPropertyChanged
foreach (var oneInstance in classInstances)
{
    var safeInstance = oneInstance;
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) =>
    {
        // start message handle loop
        while (true)
        {
            // 'AllowEntering' was bind to checkbox's 'IsChecked' property.
            if (safeInstance.AllowEntering == false)
            {
                // this should make the checkbox get checked!
                safeInstance.AllowEntering = true;
            }

            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is, sometimes the **last checkbox didn't get checked**, but **others always good**, the only different is the listBox have a scroll bar(vertical), the 4th checkbox always default **hidden** because of the small window size, then once I scroll down to make the 4th checkbox shown, it'll later get checked! this is really confuse me, please help.

Comment: You're updating the UI from a non-UI thread. You're not allowed to do that. You need to invoke all UI changes onto the UI-thread.

Comment: Where's the code that does the updating? Also, blocking a ThreadQueue thread is wasting a valuable thread and has no benefit over using a plain-old Thread.

Comment: `What every WPF app would do` is actually to data-bind the CheckBox to a ViewModel property and raise the PropertyChanged event. WPF will take care of updating the UI from the property avoiding the cross-thread mess

Comment: AllowEntering will not work (won't prevent a racing condition) for this type of synchronization use `lock`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a VirtualizingStackPanel? [I bet you are](http://miteshsureja.blogspot.ie/2011/05/virtualizing-stack-panel-in-wpf.html).

The reason for the behavior you are describing is that the checkbox that is not updating does not actually exist (it's not in the listbox). It is automatically added when you scroll and it becomes visible.

The fact you are using multiple threads is not relevant in this case.

Comment: Excellent! Never thought the WPF have this kind of optimization, but it really stuck me for days!